# After fasting during the day and one intentionally ejaculate, what can I do?

Tags: practical-islam

I normally experience sexual urges at night, but I'm yet to be married,so is it permissable for me to ejaculate?

Comment: It is not permitted to intentionally ejaculate during the daytime while fasting. As for the night then see the ruling on masturbation in the question linked below.